# Como puedo integrar 4 tablas con css

Tags: css, nodejs, vuetify

Estoy programando con node JS, vue y vuetify. Necesito integrar 4 tablas en una ventana dialog, para comparar unos productos seleccionados por el usuario. 
pero el resultado es el siguiente obtengo al integrar CSS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi codigo Css es el siguiente:

```
#tabla {
 height: 100%;
 width: 12.5rem;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 height: auto;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
 margin-right: 10px;
}
#tabla thead {

 padding: 2px;
 background: orange;
 text-align: center;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
```

Lo maximo que puedo hacer es que se repitan hacia abajo, pero no es el resultado que busco. Agradezco cualquier ayuda y consejo Muchas gracias

```
#tabla {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 height: auto;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
 margin-right: 10px;
}
#tabla thead {

 padding: 2px;
 background: orange;
 text-align: center;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
```

y el resultado es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: por qué recibes 4 tablas con datos similares? no seria mas facil realizar una consulta que te devolviese los datos todos juntos?

Comment: Hola buenos dias, esos datos son repetidos, pero son de prueba, cada producto posee diferentes  datos, por eso necesito mostrar 4 tablas. agradezco tu comentario muchas gracias

Comment: Entonces no me queda claro que deseas hacer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema es hacer las tablas flotantes (`float: left`), esto hace que se desprendan del contenedor y tu modal no tiene nada dentro para dibujarse (ya que las tablas están flotando, no en su interior)

Una solución es encerrar cada tabla en un div y darle a ese div `display: inline-block`

Otra solución es usar [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvio bastante tu ayuda